# Is it possible to do a self guided hike through Grand Canyon?

Tags: usa, grand-canyon

Is it possible we can hike/canoe WITHOUT a guide? We would like to get lost and camp out remotely. I checked the rates guided hiker/canoe. They're ridiculously expensive!

Comment: If you want to camp out remotely that's fine, but I certainly wouldn't recommend deliberately getting *lost* in the canyon. You should know where you are at all times.

Comment: I dont mean **lost** but be able to explore wherever we wish.

Comment: see also http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=grand+canyon

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg You're welcome to do it.  The thing is if anything happens the only thing you will get is a Darwin Award.

Comment: To add information about non-commercial (unguided) canoeing/kayaking--you must have a permit and they're done by lottery each year.

Answer (score 7):

If you know where you're going and you don't want a guide you're under no obligation to take one.

You can look at [Tripadvisor thread](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g143028-i157-k5375980-Can_we_do_by_ourselves_without_a_guide-Grand_Canyon_National_Park_Arizona.html) regarding the same topic and also on the [National Park Service Site](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/index.htm) for maps and other information regarding the Grand Canyon National Park.

Comment: Thanks! How about exploring gold nuggets? Metal detecting?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a guide.  But if you camp out within the National Park then you need a backcountry permit.  (See [the national park page](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/backcountry-permit.htm) on backcountry permits)  Also be aware of the warnings about hiking in the Grand Canyon -- people do get (literally) lost and the conditions can be harsh.